# Checkout a git submodule in Xcode 8 Build Phase script

Tags: xcode, git, bash, macos, ssh

I have a git repo on BitBucket for a utility project and i use it as a git submodule in other projects. I wrote an Xcode Build Phase script that clones, initializes and updates the submodule but it fails cloning with this error:

```
Cloning into '[Location of my working copy]'...
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I can do a checkout from Xcode's interface, i can do a checkout from the command line, and i can even run the same script from the command line myself, and everything works, i get prompted for my passphrase. Except when the script is run by Xcode.

I contacted BitBucket support and they pointed it out that according to the error Xcode is trying to use `/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass` to prompt me for the passphrase of my private key but it can't find the file (i also found that /usr/X11R6 is just a symlink to /opt/X11). They suggested that i check the following links:

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660237-Using-Git-with-password-authentication-on-OS-X
- https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass
- https://github.com/theseal/ssh-askpass

I installed the missing binary from the last link using Homebrew, symlinked it to the location Xcode needs it to be and got a seemingly broken dialog box:

[image: Screenshot of pop-up box]

I also tried copying the binary instead of symlinking but it didn't make a difference.

**Any ideas?**

---

Just to make sure i ran this test to see if there's a problem with my SSH configs...

```
$ ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
```

...but according to the results everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The guys over at https://github.com/theseal/ssh-askpass/ helped me figure this out.

I had to install the missing `ssh-askpass` then add my SSH key to the agent with `ssh-add -c` **before** Xcode was launched. Adding the key while Xcode was running resulted in the Build Phase script always returning an error:

`sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`

You can read the troubleshooting details [here](https://github.com/theseal/ssh-askpass/issues/14).